# How to Know Gitolite Version?

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite

I Want to know Version of Gitolite Version Which we are Using ..I tried with method Provided By SitaRam Sir Documentation. Note that i dont have any shell access to gitolite/git Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the server, you should be able to make a simple request (http or ssh) to gitolite, and you would get a **[greeting message](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/78fc24088c216686dd03d6aeba72f86559dfddf5/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L276-L294)** which includes the gitolite message.

```
# normal output
return "hello$gl_user, this is " . ( $ENV{USER} || "httpd" ) . "\@$hn running gitolite3 " . version() . " on git $gv\n";
```

For example:

```
ssh git@server info
hello u3, this is git@server running gitolite3 v3.0-11-g090b0f5 on git 1.7.7.6
```

Comment: Thanks Vonc...i am doing it with wrong username...:)

Answer (score 2):

If you installed gitolite via package manager, look up the version in the list of packages. I.e. on debian-based systems via `dpkg -l | grep gitolite`.